# Android's listView with MatrixCursor doesn't update - futureTask

Tags: android, listview, futuretask, matrixcursor

I'm writing a simple xmpp client in android and I have a problem with update `contactList`. Im using a `MatrixCursor` with `SimpleCursorAdapter` to do it. When prog updates list it starts futureTask's thread. Data is ok, but list on screen doesn't refresh because (I think) this futureTask's thread is waiting for execute?

`drawContactList` method is called from one listener when any contact change status. When I copy call to main for example it works perfectly.

Any idea how to fix it?

Code:

```
static ListView contactList;
static MatrixCursor clCursor;
static SimpleCursorAdapter adapterList;

private final String[] matrixCols = new String[] { "_id", "username", "description", "icon" };
private final String[] menuCols = new String[] {"username", "description", "icon" };
private final int[] toWhatId = new int[] { R.id.clUsername, R.id.clDescription, R.id.clStatusIcon };

...
public void drawContactList(ArrayList<Contact> contacts, Context context) {

    clCursor = new MatrixCursor(matrixCols);

    startManagingCursor(clCursor);
    if(contacts != null){
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {          
            clCursor.addRow(new Object[] { contact.id, contact.name, contact.description, contact.icon });
        }
    }
    adapterList = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.contactlist, clCursor, menuCols, toWhatId); 
    //in this line futureTask starts

    contactList.setAdapter(adapterList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Im using Handler to call this method. It works perfectly :)

```
private Handler contactListHandler = new Handler();

contactListHandler.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Presence changed: " + presence.getFrom() + " " + presence);
      drawContactList(xmppConnection.updateContacts(presence), context);
   }
});
```